# Null pointer exception from an inline conditional statement

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a bizarre null pointer exception and I can't understand why. I narrowed it down with this simple test code, which throws an NPE on the second line:

```
Long test = null;
Long result = true ? test : -1L;
```

While this code works fine:

```
Long result = true ? null : -1L;
```

This is easy enough to avoid by just not using an inline conditional statement, but can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this comes down to unboxing.  The following code will work:

```
Long two = true ? test : new Long(-1);
```

If one parameter is just -1 then it will try to unbox test so it treats both as the same type.  Unboxing null will cause the null pointer exception.  If it's null specifically in the statement, it will be smart enough to not try to unbox that.

Comment: That did it, thanks. That's pretty messed up. I'm not sure why Java feels the need to force them to be the same type.

Comment: that's just the way the ternary operator works, both sides have to cast to the same type so it can validate that both will be able to return to the object you are assigning to.

Answer (score 2):

It's attempting to unbox the reference `test` to get the `long` value, which it cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's happens because Lang encapsulate lang. So, someway, your expression trying to get some property, or the long value from Long object.. something like that...

read the documentation here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, it thinks that the expression on the right is of type long (because of the constant on the right); it therefore with autoboxing tries to get the value of test as a long, which throws and NPE.

In the second example, it treats everything as a reference value all the way through; no auto-boxing and no crash.